# Declaring and initializing variables using shorthand notation: class- versus local-variables

Tags: java

I came across an error `Syntax error on token ";", , expected`. This happens when I declare and initialize variables as class variables using a shorthand notation. If I initialize and declare the variables the exact same way as local variables this error does not occur.

The code looks exactly like this:

```
public class SomeClass{ 

double number1, number2; //On this line I get the error I mention above.
number1 = number2 = 1.0;

}
```

Why do I get this error when declaring and initializing class variables using this notation?

Comment: Works fine here: http://ideone.com/lg7TGK. Try to update the question with all code necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Radiodef The error is on the second line, not the first line.  Just because it says the error is in one place, it does not mean it is caused from else where, and in this case it is caused by `number1 = number2 = 1.0;`.

Comment: @Forseth11 You're making quite a few assumptions there. Kermit should update the question so we aren't guessing.

Comment: @Radiodef Updated code to look exactly as it looks in my IDE.

Comment: @Radiodef I assumed with the reason: "The only way this can error in java is if it were a field in a class." (And it turned out I assumed correctly with the new edit.)

Comment: @Forseth11 To be honest, I'm not really sure what the purpose of your comments is. There is no reason that you need to convince me that your guess was right and being able to guess right sometimes does not mean questions should not include all the necessary information to reproduce a problem.

Comment: @Radiodef sorry. I was just trying to explain why I made my assumption, but never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
public class SomeClass
{ 
    double number1, number2; 

    {
        number1 = number2 = 1.0;
    }
}
```

You can not write statements directly in a class body; usually statements are in method bodies; they can also appear in static or instance initializer blocks

```
public class Foo
{

    static{  print("foo"); }  // executed during class initialization

    { print("foo"); }  // executed in constructor 

    print("foo");  // Error!

}
```

JLS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassBody

```
ClassBodyDeclaration:
  ClassMemberDeclaration
  InstanceInitializer
  StaticInitializer
  ConstructorDeclaration

ClassMemberDeclaration:
  FieldDeclaration
  MethodDeclaration
  ClassDeclaration
  InterfaceDeclaration
  ;
```

For some reason, empty statement is allowed:)

```
class Foo
{
    ;
}
```

(not really - the lone ";" is simply discarded, not counted as a statement)

Comment: I'm surprised this was not(not yet, possibly) mentioned in the book I'm currently working from. I appreciate your informative- and well written- answer very much.

Comment: instance initializer block is not used very often. but it can be handy sometimes....

Comment: I look forward to applying this knowledge sometime.

Answer (score 1):

This error only occurs if it is a field so I am assuming this is a field.

This happens because `number1 = number2 = 1.0;` is not initializing a field for the class.  Instead it is a line of code which must be in side of a method block.

To fix this you can initialize it inside a method or constructor or do:

```
double number1 = 1.0, number2 = 1.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

When declaring class variable you need to leave it uninitialized or initialize an the same time. If you want to initialize it later, you can put the code in constructor

```
public class MyClass {
  double number1 = 1.0, number2;

  public MyClass {
    number2  = 2.0;
  }

}
```